# Will a schematic ever require different combinations of materials?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

If I'm crafting light armor for a mage, I'd much prefer the utility/defense slots to take cloth, as those yield stats and bonuses better befitting a mage For example, metal in a utility slot yield strength or constitution (or a combination of the two). Strength is fairly useless for a mage, and while constitution isn't, it's not as desirable as magic or willpower, which is what cloth in a utility slots yield.

The [Warden Battlemage Armor](http://dragonage3.wiki.fextralife.com/Warden+Battlemage+Armor+Schematic) schematic requires 15 cloth (armor slot), 9 metal (utility slot), 9 leather (defense slot), and 1 (optional) masterwork.

This schematic is sold by a vendor in the Dalish Camp in the Exalted Plains. Is this schematic set in stone in the materials it requires? Or, since so much of the other loot in the game is randomly generated, will the vendor ever carry a schematic that requires all cloth instead (or some other combination)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, every schematic has fixed requirements, which is a combination of all materials (cloth, metal, leather, and masterwork if applicable). So the answer for your question is "No", unfortunately.
However, depends on the type of the schematic, the ratio of required materials are different. For example, light armor requires more cloth, medium armor requires more leather and heavy armor requires more metal.

I believe the developer intention is to avoid the unbalanced craft like your example (full cloth schematic => full magic or willpower for mage) and make the character not too overpower